# ValueError: math domain error in numpy linalg.py when calling lstsq(a, b, rcond=-1)

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.4

When i try to call a module in numpy's ( 1.9.2)  Linalg.py i.e

def lstsq(a, b, rcond=-1):

i get an error in the last line of the code below

```
File "/opt/graphics.py", line 62, in plotTestResult
a = np.linalg.lstsq(x, y)
File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1837, in lstsq
nlvl = max( 0, int( math.log( float(min(m, n))/2. ) ) + 1 )
ValueError: math domain error
```

I have a sample code that i am working with in python 3.4 . The call was working in Python 2.7 but in python 3.4 i get an error now when i call the same module.

```
def plotTestResult(tradesFile, regressionType=LINEAR_REGRESSION, show=False, resolution={"x": 800, 'y': 600},
               pdf=False):
dates = []
balances = []
volumes = []
swaps = []
epochDates = []
lineFit = []
balancesForFit = []
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(resolution['x'] / 100, resolution['y'] / 100))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[4, 1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
plt.title('Test Result')

with open(tradesFile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i > 0:
            dates.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(row[3], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
            balances.append(float(row[10]))
            volumes.append(float(row[6]))
            swaps.append(float(row[13]))
        i = i + 1

for j in range(0, i - 1):
    if regressionType == LINEAR_REGRESSION:
        balancesForFit.append(balances[j] - balances[0])
    if regressionType == EXPONENTIAL_REGRESSION:
        balancesForFit.append(log(balances[j]) - log(balances[0]))
    epochDates.append(in_unix(dates[j]) - in_unix(dates[0]))

x = np.array(epochDates)
y = np.array(balancesForFit)

x = x[:, np.newaxis]

# The line below is the Line throwing the error 

a, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(x, y) # throwing an Error in numpy  linalg.py



.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

This last line is generating the error mentioned above  i.e

```
ValueError: math domain error
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong in the code . Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: Are you really sure that your `x` and `y` arrays are "good" (i.e. are not degenerate)?

Comment: I can reproduce that error if the length of one of the dimensions of `x` is 0.  Check the shape of `x`--either use a debugger, or add `print(x.shape)` before the call to `lstsq`.